# JavaFX Loader returning an IOException

Tags: exception, javafx

Trying to load an FXML file in Eclipse and continue to get exceptions. Here is my main:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    static Tracker money = new Tracker(0,0,0);
    static Tracker steel = new Tracker(0,0,0);
    static Tracker titanium = new Tracker(0,0,0);
    static Tracker plant = new Tracker(0,0,0);
    static Tracker power = new Tracker(0,0,0);
    static Tracker heat = new Tracker(0,0,0);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("board.fxml"));
                Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                System.out.print("NullPointerException Caught");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.print("IOException Caught");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    public static void nextGen() {
        money.produce();
        steel.produce();
        titanium.produce();
        plant.produce();
        power.produce();
        heat.produce();
    }
    
    public static void change() {
        money.change();
        steel.change();
        titanium.change();
        plant.change();
        power.change();
        heat.change();
    }   
}
```

I did the separate catches to see what is actually happening for Exceptions as I thought it was NullPointer at first (may still be that if a null val into the loader would give that) but the catch is happening with the IOException. I don't really know where to go from here, just would like some guidance.

EDIT

Added e.printStackTrace() per suggestion:

```
IOException Caughtjavafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/pcher/eclipse-workspace/board/bin/application/board.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:933)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at board/application.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.BoardCo
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:931)
    ... 17 more
```

Here is the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TitledPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Terraforming Mars Tracker" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.BoardCo">
   <content>
      <GridPane prefHeight="388.0" prefWidth="598.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="154.0" minHeight="154.0" prefHeight="154.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="154.0" minHeight="154.0" prefHeight="154.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="113.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="41.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Money">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Production:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Change:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Total:" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Steel" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Production:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Change:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Total:" />
                              <TextField editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                           </children>
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Titanium" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Production:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Change:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Total:" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                           </children>
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Plant" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Production:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Change:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Total:" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                           </children>
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Power" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Production:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Change:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Total:" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                           </children>
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <TitledPane animated="false" text="Heat" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Production:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Change:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" text="Total:" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                           </children>
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnNextGenClicked" text="Next Generation" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnChangeClicked" text="Change" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </content>
</TitledPane>
```

And here is my controller (bare bones at the moment):

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class BoardController {

    // Event Listener on Button.onAction
    @FXML
    public void btnNextGenClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        Main.nextGen();
    }
    // Event Listener on Button.onAction
    @FXML
    public void btnChangeClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        Main.change();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question, add the full stack trace formatted as code. Don’t just output the exception name if you decide to catch the exception use `e.printStackTrace()` or a logging framework to log the full stack trace.

Comment: Add the fxml and controller to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the question having what is supposed to need, new to posting on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the help with the question formatting, does this have everything now?

Comment: The stack trace tells you the problem. Your controller class is called `application.BoardController`, but in the FXML you specify `application.BoardCo`.

Comment: unrelated: don't use static scope for methods/fields - instead learn how to pass parameters/instances around!

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that James

If I start getting more into it I definitely will kloepatra, but for now this is gonna be doing something pretty simple and be used by me alone.